# How to DataBind Multiple Items with VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding

I'm running the following query:

```
' Show which halls they are eligible for.
        Dim dbRooms As New pbu_housingEntities
        Dim gender As String = Session("gender").ToString
        Dim hall As String = CStr(Session("hall"))
        Dim selectedRooms = (From sh In dbRooms.Rooms _
                             Where sh.gender = gender _
                             Where sh.current_occupancy < sh.max_occupancy _
                             Where sh.is_available = True _
                             Where sh.building_name = hall _
                             Select sh.room1, actual_available = sh.max_occupancy - sh.current_occupancy
                             )
        rptrRooms.DataSource = selectedRooms
        rptrRooms.DataBind()
```

Which, as you can see, is bound to a repeater. Now, it contains multiple values and I'd like to display them in a nicely formatted way, pseudo code below:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptrRooms" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Choose_Room">
  <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnChooseRoom" runat="server"
        CommandName="<%# Container.DataItem.Room1.ToString %>" Text="<%# Container.DataItem.Room1 %> : Available : <%# Container.DataItem.actual_available %>"
         />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Text='<%# String.Format("{0} : Available : {1}", Container.DataItem.Room1, Container.DataItem.actual_available) %>'
```

Comment: I gave that a try, but it doesn't like the double "", so I changed the inside ones to ''. It ran but returned the following error:
BC30201: Expression expected.
From the source error:
Line 6:      <asp:Repeater ID="rptrRooms" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Choose_Room">
Line 7:        <ItemTemplate>
Line 8:              <asp:Button ID="btnChooseRoom" runat="server"
Line 9:              CommandName="<%# Container.DataItem.Room1.ToString %>" Text="<%# String.Format('{0} : Available : {1}', Container.DataItem.Room1, Container.DataItem.actual_available) %>"
Line 10:              />

Comment: Okay, this was really stupid - I just needed to reverse the quotations - now the outer are ' and the inner are " and it works just fine. Thanks for your help!